# SELECTing n rows for each GROUP with WHERE condition

Tags: mysql, group-by, subquery, greatest-n-per-group, mariadb-10.5

I `SELECT` n rows for each `ArticleID` from `TagMap` table

```
SELECT a.ArticleID,a.TagID FROM TagMap a
LEFT JOIN TagMap b ON a.ArticleID = b.ArticleID AND a.TagID < b.TagID
GROUP BY a.ArticleID,a.TagID
HAVING COUNT(b.TagID) < 3
ORDER BY a.ArticleID,a.TagID
```

I want to add a condition to limit the query to specific tags,

```
SELECT a.ArticleID,a.TagID FROM TagMap a
  LEFT JOIN TagMap b ON a.ArticleID = b.ArticleID AND a.TagID < b.TagID
    WHERE a.TagID IN(SELECT TagID FROM Tags WHERE Status=1)
    AND b.TagID IN(SELECT TagID FROM Tags WHERE Status=1)
  GROUP BY a.ArticleID,a.TagID
  HAVING COUNT(b.TagID) < 3
  ORDER BY a.ArticleID,a.TagID
```

If I use the condition as sub-query, I would need to sub-queries. If I use the condition as `JOIN`, I need two `JOIN`s since the above `JOIN` is `LEFT JOIN`.

Is there an easier way to do so?

Comment: The wanted result is not very clear. You want to show all articles but only 3 tags per article?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ I edited the query to clarify. I want 3 tags per article.

Comment: Can you please give an example of the before data and the after data output you're looking for? It's still a bit unclear what you're trying to achieve. Your `WHERE` clause has the same condition written twice (`WHERE a.TagID IN(SELECT TagID FROM Tags WHERE Status=1)`) which doesn't do anything differently logically.

Comment: @J.D. sorry, it was a typo. The second `a.TagID` is `b.TagID`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the status conditions to th on clause

```
  SELECT a.ArticleID,a.TagID FROM TagMap a
      LEFT JOIN TagMap b ON a.ArticleID = b.ArticleID AND a.TagID < b.TagID AND a.Status =1 AND b.Status = 1
      GROUP BY a.ArticleID,a.TagID
      HAVING COUNT(b.TagID) < 3
      ORDER BY a.ArticleID,a.TagID
```

the subselects aren't needed at al if a status is a independent if a or b you take the row, if it isn't you dismiss it.

If you put the status condition in a WHERE clause or in the ON doesn't change the execution plan.

But you could change the index to include the Status

Comment: so silly of me, not to think this way!

Comment: it took me also some time, to figure it out